# Django admin css issue

Tags: css, django, apache, django-admin

I have django installed on my web server, and I am having issues with the css and iamge files. I made an apache alias that reroutes requests to the proper folder where the admin's css files are. The issue is that it displays properly in firefox, but not chrome or IE. In chrome or IE, it is not using ANY css or image files. Going to the following url displaysthe css at that location, so I know it is rerouting correctly, and the admin html file is using this url. But it just doesn't use the css in chrome or IE.

"http://www.mysite.com/static/admin/css/dashboard.css"

static/admin/ is an alias in my apache settings. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the css and images are not cached in firefox?

Comment: what happens when you directly visit a link to a file ?

Comment: If I directly link to a .css file, it pulls up the source for that file. Did i understand you correctly? Also, it can't be cached, as I have never gone to that admin site in firefox, until I was curious if it'd work in firefox.

Comment: and how about the browser cache for chrome and IE ?

Comment: I cleared them both. But I had never been to the site on IE or firefox until I gave up trying to get it to work in chrome. I had NEVER gone to the site in firefox, then the first time I did it worked perfectly. iI had never gone to the site in IE, and when I did, it displayed the same way as chrome. I have been using firefox for the admin page, and it is working with pages I have never gone to before in the admin plugin(so I dont see how it could be a cache issue)

Comment: How about a link to the live site? Guessing at this stuff is a Waste of Time™.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inspect element to figure out your css files really loaded or cached in firefox.
If it is loaded but cannot show in chrome and IE, the problem is because of the css you have used 
BUT
If it is not loaded you should correct the alias

I think better way to have a good routing is to embed in in urls.py file
This way the django server handled it and of course you can check it on your pc then upload into the server.

if you can take your website address, Perhaps I can do more helps.

Regards
Mohammad